# I am new to python programming, I need to count the user's names by taking user input who has length more than 5 characters in their names

Tags: python, python-3.x, count

count users' names:

```
def counts(a):
    count = 0
    for j in a:
        if len(j) >= 5:
            count = count+1
            return count
    print(count)

b = int(input("How many names do you wanna print? "))
for i in range(b):
    a = input("Enter user's name one by one: ")

ans = counts(a)
print("these are the counted number of the user's names who has length more than 5 letters in the names: ",ans)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should return the `count` only after completion the `for` loop, like this:

```py
def counts(a):
    count = 0
    for j in a:
        if len(j) >= 5:
            count = count+1
    print(count)
    return count
```

**UPD**
The rest of the code should be fixed as well.
Try this:

```py
a = []
b=int(input("How many names do you wanna print? "))
for i in range(b):
    a.append(input("Enter user's name one by one: "))

ans=counts(a)
print("these are the counted number of the user's names who has length more than 5 letters in the names: ",ans)
```

Comment: after doing this, it is showing me this output:                                                              How many names do you wanna print? 3
Enter user's name one by one: weffege
Enter user's name one by one: weffwefefe
Enter user's name one by one: e
0
these are the counted number of the user's names who has length more than 5 letters in the names:  0

Comment: This is because you have to fix the rest of your code too. Please see the updated answer

Comment: can you tell me why did you use list? and append?

Comment: ` counts(a)` receives some `a` that should be a list, not a single string. So I have to collect all the inputted strings to some list in order to pass them to the `counts()` function. Correct? So I'm appending (adding) each received input to the list and then passing it to that method.

Comment: thank you sooo muchhhhhhh, I got the answer

Answer (score 0):

You arent storing the names as a `list` so they can be iterated as intended.

```
a = []
for i in range(b):
    a.append(input("Enter user's name one by one: "))
```

And your indentation is wrong in `counts`. You're returning in the firstiteration of the loop:

```
def counts(a):
    count = 0
    for j in a:
        if len(j) >= 5:
            count = count+1
    print(count)
    return count
```

Answer (score 0):

I hate `for loop`s ! You can do it this way:

```py
def more_than_five(a):
    More_than_5 = [True for item in a if len(item)>=5]
    Count = sum(More_than_5)
    return Count
    
    
print(more_than_five(input('enter the names:\n').split()))
```

Answer (score 0):

this it what i would use:

```
names=[]
count_to_print=int(input("How many names do you wanna print? "))
counter_long_names=0
for counter in range(count_to_print):
    name=input("Enter user's name one by one: ")
    names.append(name)
    if len(name)>5:  # use >= for 5 or more characters
        counter_long_names+=1
        # names.append(name)    #here if you only want to store the long names

print(counter_long_names)
```

you can leave out all the lines with "names" in the line if you dont want to store the names